# Every time I select the select field the on change event is activated but the old value is not deleted

Tags: jquery, select

Every time I enter the select field the on change event is activated but the old value is not deleted. What I want is that the old attr is removed from the option and the new one that is clicked on should get the attr.

See Image:

[image: Image Option Attr Selected]

I do want a single select and not multiple.

My Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data, 
    postData, 
    brandsArr = [], 
    uniqBrandsArr = [], 
    typeArr = [], 
    fuelArr = [];

    var brand = $('#brand'),
    brandOption = brand.find('#option-brand');


    data = {
        'action': 'ajax'
    };  

    jQuery.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        postData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        jQuery.each(postData, function(index, value) {
            if(value.meta_key === 'brand') {
                brandsArr.push(value.meta_value);
            } else if(value.meta_key === 'type') { 
                typeArr.push(value.meta_value);
            } else if(value.meta_key === 'fuel') {
                fuelArr.push(value.meta_value);
            }
        });

        var uniqBrandsArr = brandsArr.filter(function(value, index){
            return brandsArr.indexOf(value) == index;
        });

        jQuery.each(uniqBrandsArr, function(index, value){
            brand.append($('<option>',
            {
                id: 'option-brand',
                value: value,
                text: value
            }));    
        });

        brand.on('change', function(){
            brandSelectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('selected', true);

        }); 


    });

});
```

What I want when I click the select field again and choose a new option the old attribute selected option must be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I click the select field again and choose a new option the old attribute selected option must be removed.

So you have to deselect every options before selecting the new one...

```
brand.on('change', function(){

  // Add this line:
  $(this).children("option").attr('selected', false);

  brandSelectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('selected', true);

});
```

Here's a simple demo... Inspect the markup to see the attributes.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {

  // Removes all selected attributes
  $(this).children("option").attr('selected', false);

  // Adds the attribute on the currently selected
  $(this).children("option:selected").attr('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Zero</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**

Since the options are dynamically added, try:

```
$(document).on('change', '#brand', function(){
```

Instead of `brand.on('change', function(){`

Comment: It's selecting the first element and it's not changing? and when i try to get the values of the option field, they are blank inside the console.

Comment: can you explain my why i have to use it like that? i am a starter coding

Comment: Best is you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about delegation...

Comment: I still have the same error.. when i remove this line $(this).children("option").attr('selected', false); it's multi selecting and thats what i don't want.

Comment: It works fine [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qwKZGW?editors=1011)...

Comment: I just don't get it, what can be the problem?

Comment: I don't know... The only thing I can think of is you possibly use the id `brand` on more than one `<select>`...